# Is the stack pre-allocated in a process?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86-64, stack-memory

Well, my question is as follows, I saw somewhere that a linux process allocates 8 MiB on the stack to be used, if I have a C program for example, that I only allocate two variables on the stack, it is right to say that I allocated or is it better to say that I just reused that space? Since a process allocates 8 MiB on the stack it does not depend on the size that I am going to use in my program, as long as it does not exceed my stack, that is, whichever term is appropriate, I will allocate a data on the stack or I will reuse a data that has already been allocated by a linux process?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f() {
   int x = 5;
   printf("Value = %d End = %p\n", x, &x);
}

void g() {
   int y = 10;
   printf("Value = %d End = %p\n", y, &y);
}

int main(){

  f();
  g();
  return 0;
}
```

See that the addresses will be the same, because I reused the size that had already been allocated, the same wouldn't happen with malloc, summarizing the term Allocated right data in the Stack isn't very correct?

Comment: You allocated variables on stack but their lifetime is limited by a function call. After function exit space is automatically deallocated. But stack allocation in address space of process is another story.

Comment: I'd say your understanding is 100% correct.

Comment: The same absolutely *could* happen with `malloc()`, provided that you `free()`d the first object before `malloc()`ing the second.

Comment: When `f()` is called, space is reserved on the stack for `x`. When `f()` returns, that space is released. When `g()` is called, space is reserved for `y`, and it's likely to be exactly the same space that was previously reserved for `x`. When `g()` returns, the space is released. The terms you use: "reserve" "release" or "allocate" "deallocate" are up to you.

Comment: In some sense, all allocation involves reusing memory at one level or another.  Calling `malloc` may "reuse" memory already allocated to the process, or it may request more memory from the OS, which in turn will satisfy the request by "reusing" physical memory that was previously used for something else.  So even if the stack memory was already allocated to the process (at the level of the OS), it is still correct to say that adjusting the stack pointer allocates more stack space (at the level of the program itself).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the stack pre-allocated in a process?

On a stack-based architecture, a process will have stack space available to it from the beginning of its execution.  That could be described as "pre-allocated".  However, do note that in some contexts, it may be possible for a process's stack to be extended during the lifetime of the process.  Perhaps that changes how you would view it?

In any case, that has little to do with whether the process of assigning storage space for automatic variables should be described as "allocation".  Although it has technical implications, it is of little account linguistically that such space may be carved out of the stack, as opposed to out of some other area of memory controlled by the process.  The *lifetimes* of such objects do obey different rules than the lifetimes of `malloc`ated objects, but so what?

> if I have a C program for example, that I only allocate two variables on the stack, it is right to say that I allocated or is it better to say that I just reused that space?

People are likely to understand you just fine either way.  Although I'm sure there are some who would quibble over whether "allocate" is technically correct for automatic variables, it is nevertheless widely used for them.  If you are conversing with people, as opposed to writing technical documentation to which the distinction is important, then I would not hesitate to use "allocate" to describe assigning storage space to automatic variables.

Comment: As proof the term is correct, existence of `alloca()` function can be given.

Comment: Space below the stack pointer (and red-zone) can be asynchronously clobbered (e.g. by signal handlers, and in some corner cases by debuggers if you ask it to call a function in the context of your process). Space above can't.  That's one reason we call it "allocated" or "reserved".  In theory a system could reclaim pages below the stack pointer under memory pressure (like an implicit `madvise(MADV_FREE)`), instead of swapping them out.  In practice Linux doesn't do that, and compilers don't emit code to make an `madvise` syscall when returning from a function with non-tiny local arrays.